# Custom Headers in Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, reverse-proxy

i have this nginx.conf

```
server {

listen  <%= ENV['NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['NGINX_PORT'] %>;
server_name proxy-oapp.rhcloud.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass https://app-oapp.rhcloud.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_set_header Host api-oapp.rhcloud.com;
    proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X_Auth_Token $upstream_http_x_auth_token;
    proxy_set_header X_User_Id $upstream_http_x_user_id;
    proxy_pass https://api-oapp.rhcloud.com/; 
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

The client add in headers the id and the token for authentication as:
X_Auth_Token: MYTOKEN
X_User_Id: MYID

But in the server i haven't the token in the headers.

WHY????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the underscore.
I must change this

```
X_Auth_Token: MYTOKEN 
X_User_Id: MYID
```

whit this:

```
X-Auth-Token: MYTOKEN 
X-User-Id: MYID
```

Comment: you can also use directive [underscores_in_headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) it is off by default